# Optimized search.How to reduce the complexity ?

Tags: facebook, algorithm, facebook-graph-api, graph, graph-traversal

Here is a problem I'm trying to solve using graph algorithms. Answer to this question is easy if one is familiar with different graph traversal algorithms. What I want to learn is how can we reduce the complexity of this problem?

> Let say we have to traverse in someone's network - Friends, Friends of
>   Friends (FoF) and FoFoF (1st, 2nd, 3rd Degree.. up to 6th degree) to
>   search for a particular thing, say 'people living in California'. The
>   complexity of the problem greatly increases when you have 1000 friends
>   and your 1000 friends have 1000 friends each and so on.
>
> Let's say we want to do an optimized search, where you know the
>   destination node (here, a person living in California). How will you
>   reduce the complexity of the problem?
>
> The program you submit should return the degree by which that person
>   is connected to you. [where the 'destination node' is your Degree 1st
>   (Friend), or 2nd (friend of friend) or 3rd Degree (FoFoF) or a Degree
>   greater than 3rd degree].

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your graph is unweighted, doing Breadth First Search will give you shortest paths (which effectively are the degrees that you need). If the destination is known you can also use Dijkstra's Algorithm to find a shortest path to that specific node, although if the graph is unweighted just doing the BFS will be more efficient as it's complexity is lower than Dijkstra's. Also if I understand correctly your output has to cover only 4 cases: Degrees 1,2,3 or higher than that. If so, you can just BFS the first three levels and store the results. Then you can answer the question in constant time by checking for the existence of such person in the data obtained via BFS.